# imagejpeg save file does not work

Tags: php, jpeg

I managed to display image on browser but I cannot save it using imagejpeg (I don't see any image saved in the server). I have been trying for hours and also tested out the folder by using is_writable as mentioned in this post asked by someone else [PHP imagejpeg save file doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672965/php-imagejpeg-save-file-doesnt-work) .
But it still doesn't work and on chrome, I don't see any error except broken image icon but on IE, it shows error like this 
"**Warning**:  imagejpeg() [function.imagejpeg]: Unable to open" the file is not writable

Here is my code.

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
$filename = 'little.jpg';
 $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename); 
imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_CONTRAST,$_POST["amount"]);

imagejpeg($im,"test.jpg");   

imagedestroy($im); 

if (is_writable('test.jpg')) {
    echo 'The file is writable';
} else {
    echo 'The file is not writable';
}
```

Anyone can help,please? thank you.
P.S: I also want to display the image on the browser and save the image at the same time. Is imagejpeg able to do it? If not, is there better way to do it? Thank you.

Edit: When I checked whether my folder is writable, it echoed 'the file is writable' but when I checked whether test.jpg is writable, it echoed 'the file is not writable'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That error indicates that your PHP script does not have permission to write to that location on the server.  Use your FTP software to CHMOD (change permissions) to allow write to the directory you are trying to store these in.  That should do it unless your webhost has disabled PHP from writing files locally at all (in which case, you should talk to them and see what options are available).

Comment: How do I change the permission? But when I tested the folder which it is supposed to write in, it echo as 'it is writable'. I tested as follows: if (is_writable('./')) {
    echo 'The file is writable';
} else {
    echo 'The file is not writable';
}

Comment: the is_writable() should be pointing to a directory, not a filename string...so that is mixed up anyway.  the permissions are set in your FTP software, but they all work differently.  You want to find something that either says "permissions" or "CHMOD" and set it to 755 for the directory where you are storing your image.  Also, i usually use a full server path for storing files...it is not "necessary" in most cases, but does give me  better debugging data if something is not going where i thought it was.  I use something like:  $filename = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/images/test.jpg';

Comment: thx a lot for your answers. It is actually server problem which I managed to solve it because of your answers.